# My params is coming up as nil. How do you create a new params for a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

```
#today_free_time.row
.col-md-2.col-sm-12.arrow_container{:style => "text-align:right;"}
  - if @dates >= 1
    = link_to movies_path(@dates), date: 'sub' do
      /date = date - 1
      %i.fa.fa-caret-left
  - else
    %i.fa.fa-caret-left


.col-md-3.col-sm-12.today_container
  .date_font
    %p 
    %p
      =get_month
    %p 
      =get_day
    %p 
      =get_year

.col-md-5.col-sm-12.free_time_list_container
  %text_backgroud
    .agenda_date Free Time:
    %p 
      =free_time
      =@dates

.col-md-2.col-sm-12.arrow_container{:style => "text=align:left;"}
  = link_to movies_path(@dates), date: 'add' do
    %i.fa.fa-caret-right
```

there's the code in my index file

```
if params[:add] == "add"
  @dates += 1
  logger.debug "*************Dates1 #{@dates}"
end

logger.debug "*************params #{params[:date].inspect}"
logger.debug "*************Dates2 #{@dates}"
```

there's the code in my controller

I am a little confused on `params`. Right now the `params :date` is coming up `nil` when I click on the `link_to`. I want to be able to click the `link_to` and my index file will be able to increment dates. So I will be able to go up a date or down depending on which `link_to` is clicked.  Do I need to create a new `params` somewhere are what?

Comment: The api documentation has examples below it showing different ways to use the method call and what url is generated from each. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Answer (score 0):

```
# link_to movies_path(@dates), date: 'add' do
```

changes to

```
link_to movies_path(@dates,date: 'add') do
```